# android number format for germany

Tags: android, phone-number

is there a public algorithm that formats German phone numbers (mobile and landlines)? I saw there is a method to format phone numbers `PhoneNumberUtils.getFormatTypeForLocale(Locale locale)` but this is only for NANP countries, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NANPA).

Comment: Only NANP? no, there's also JAPAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) can do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Like most android documentation [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html) very poorly created. Try Locale.GERMANY as method input. If the locale format is unavaible like you mentioned, you have to write your own method. Maybe extending PhoneNumberUtils and overriding that method is a good practice. Good luck anyway :).

Edit: aspartame's answer seems more logical to me.